# Nginx proxy with varying source address

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have a **working** nginx configuration to proxy all requests to a server from a range of source IPs. I currently have 20 source IPs set up, and the configuration is quite massive. I removed the other 18 blocks for brevity.

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this. I need to add upwards of 100 IPs and the configuration would be too large this way. There must be a better way!

**To clarify:** I need the requests to originate from one of 100 random ip addresses provisioned on the server. The destination server will see the proxied request come from one of 100 addresses.

Would HAProxy or another alternative be better suited for this kind of task?

Simplified nginx configuration:

```
# nginx proxies all requests to one of these servers
upstream cluster {
  # one server line for every server block configured below
  server 127.0.0.1:8000;
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
  # 18 more...  

  least_conn;
  keepalive 16;
}

# one server block for every source ip address configured
server {
  listen 8000;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://destination;
    # ip address below is one of 20 addresses outgoing requests will bind to
    proxy_bind 10.0.0.1;
  }
}

server {
  listen 8001;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://destination;
    # ip address below is one of 20 addresses outgoing requests will bind to
    proxy_bind 10.0.0.2;
  }
}

# 18 more server blocks

# redirect all http traffic to https
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# proxy requests to upstream, which proxies requests to destination
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://cluster;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
  }
}
```

Comment: The configuration works just fine. There's no need to specify an IP for the listen directive.

Comment: I removed the other 19 servers from the upstream block and removed the other 19 server blocks. They are identical to the rest, except different ports. There is no need to post those.

The question is quite clear. This configuration isn't feasable for upwards of 100 addresses. There must be a better way.

Comment: Is it only the https traffic that gets sent to the upstream servers defined as cluser? is "Destination" the same in each?

Comment: Correct, all http traffic is redirected to https. Each upstream proxies to the same destination. The only difference is the IP that is bound. I need to be able to bind to one of 100 random IPs without specifying 100 different server blocks.

Comment: In which case I think you would need nginx with the perl module and write a bit of code to generate the IP

Comment: You didn't describe why do you need all of those nested blocks with proxy_bind. May be (from my point of view it's not "may be", but rather "I'm sure" ) it's enough to add just an `upstream` block and forward to it.

Comment: I did describe why I needed the extra server blocks. I need the requests to originate from one of 100 ip addresses that I have provisioned on the server. proxy_bind lets me bind to one of those addresses. So I need to set up 100 server blocks, one for each source ip. Unless you know of a better way?